# Convert image to CAD file (DWG or DXF)

Tags: .net, image, aspose, dwg

I have a .NET C# program that needs to convert an image (be it *BMP, JPEG, PNG*) into an AutoCAD file (*DWG or DXF*). I've tried several ways mentioned here in other forums, but without success. I tried [Aspose](https://products.aspose.com/imaging/net/conversion/bmp-to-dxf/) but there they only import DWG and don't convert to DWG.

Could anyone help me with some approach to this conversion or an API for .NET ?

I tried to convert using Aspose's API, with [this link](https://products.aspose.com/imaging/net/conversion/bmp-to-dxf/); I tried the exact same code but it doesn't seem to work because the generated DXF is empty.

The most promising approach for my .NET C# program seems to be via Aspose, but as I mentioned, I was unsuccessful.

Comment: You'll have to post your attempt and hope that people can help you make it work - otherwise this will just be a request for help finding a toolkit, which is off-topic.

Comment: I tried the below code available in Aspose library but it saves an empty file, there is no content in output.dxf


**`using Aspose.Imaging;
usingSystem;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

string templatesFolder = @"c:\Users\USER\templates\";
using (var image = Aspose.Imaging.Image.Load(Path.Combine(templatesFolder, @"template.bmp")))
{
    var exportOptions = new Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.DxfOptions(){ TextAsLines = true,ConvertTextBeziers = true};
    image.Save(Path.Combine(templatesFolder, "output.dxf"), exportOptions);
}`**

Comment: Reading your question again, you do realize that dwg/dxf is not an image format as such but a CAD format, right? I mean, it can have elements in it that are bitmapped images, but that's not what the overall format is about.

Comment: Okay, so basically I should convert the image to a vectorized type (SVG for example) and then upload it to a CAD file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with Aspose.CAD library:

```cs
using (Image cadImage = Image.Load("input.png"))
{
    cadImage.Save("output.dxf", new DxfOptions());
}
```

Disclosure: I work as Aspose.CAD developer at Aspose.